# Using IE6 in Windows XP mode to access an instance of Tomcat running on the host (Windows 7)

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have

- Windows 7 as a host machine with Tomcat running on port 8080
- Windows XP mode (virtual machine) with stock internet explorer 6, running inside the windows 7 instance

I need to ensure that the website I am developing supports IE6 (to a degree). What is the easiest way to access the Windows 7 instance of Tomcat, from inside the virtual machine (XP Mode)?

I tried navigating to *localhost:8080/*... but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: does 8080 works on normal version? i'd rather setup a more proper vitalization environment, like using vmware stuff

Comment: Have a look here:
http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2009/12/24/How-to-get-Windows-7-XP-Mode-Apps-to-talk-to-SQL-2008-on-your-Windows-7-Host-OS.aspx

Comment: A fresh tomcat installation on the vm machhine will cost you 5 minutes ... Trying localhost:8080 on the vm is like calling 127.0.0.1 on the vm  and not 127.0.0.1 of the host machine. The ip with nickname 'localhost' is not shared between the 2 machines

Answer (score 0):

IE6 is a dead browser and Windows XP is an unsupported operating system.

At the time of writing, less than 4% of the entire world uses the outdated and unsupported browser according to Microsoft's IE6 countdown. https://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown

I strongly recommend that you don't waste time adding extra compatibility for such outdated and scarcely used technologies, with the exception of your boss requiring you to do so.